# Low cost temperature and humidity logger

Tags: wireless, ethernet, scientific-instruments

I am looking for an interior temperature and humidity logger that meets the following requirements:

- Log access via WiFi or wired ethernet. USB not acceptable.
- Ability to store at least 48 hours of data if no connection available.
- Sampling rate every 1 hour or faster.
- Multiple devices can be used on same network / with same PC.
- Temperature accuracy at least +/- 0.5C.
- Relative humidity accuracy at least +/- 1%.
- Temperature range at least -10C to +40C.
- Windows or Linux compatibility.
- Under $50.

Some sacrifice in accuracy may be OK if necessary to keep the cost down. Barometric pressure would be a nice-to-have but not required.

The following things do not matter:

- Battery vs. wall power.
- Battery life.
- Wall-mount vs. anything else.
- Log viewing can be with proprietary software, no standard protocols or storage formats needed.

I am also open to suggestions for reliable components for a DIY solution.

I found [this device](http://www.weathershop.com/wifith.htm), which has almost all of the features I am looking for aside from humidity accuracy (+/- 2.5%), except it is currently $159.50 USD ($140.80 minimum cost from random small vendors on Google) and has [terrible Amazon reviews](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008LVQBI0) (that appears to be the TH+ higher temperature accuracy model but I have a hunch the hardware quality is similar).

I am finding that the network access requirement is severely limiting options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want a raspberry pi or arduino to do this. I found this website 
https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/temperature/

they take a 35$ raspberry pi, wire in a 5$ sensor and they were able to record temp readings.

Raspberry pi can connect to your network using wifi or ethernet. There are simple scripts that would tell your pi to text you every hour the current temp.

I hope this suggestion fits the bill, or at least leads in the right direction.

Comment: Just a heads up you will want a RPi instead of arduino. I was creating the same type of project and the arduino is not stable enough for long term use. After several hours it would crap out. It wasn't just one either, i tested 9 arduinos. RPi never gave me these issues. just my experience

Comment: Agreed, RPI is the way to go.

Comment: After a long time searching for off-the-shelf products I wasn't able to find anything affordable, so this is what I ended up doing. I had been hoping to avoid the effort of constructing my own logger but it wasn't actually that bad in the end. The RPi's are working well.